# What are the basic principles of experimental electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, soft-question, history

I want to learn about experimental physics in the context of electrodynamics and electrostatics. Basically I'd like to know how we are able to measure different quantities in this field (electric field, potential, etc):

1. What are the basic measuring devices and principles? For example in Griffiths' book he mentions how measuring the radius of a particle in a particle accelerator can tell us what is the momentum.
2. What are some significant milestones in the field? For example Millikan's oil drops experiment.